# Ubuntu 14.04 new install on Dell laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, laptop, system-installation

I managed to burn the latest version to DVD and installed it on a Dell Latitude laptop having Windows XP Pro. End result is the laptop will not reboot to either OS! After Ubuntu was done installing I clicked the "Restart" button and nothing happened. I was forced to simply shut the laptop down. So where do I go from here now that the laptop is useless?

Answer (score 0):

No you would just have installed GRUB in the wrong place.

You can follow the straight forward instructions on how to fix it here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I

The basic gist is that you load into the live disk and reinstall grub in the correct place from there.